# Video Encoding/Trans coding Conversion Dedicated Server

Tags: centos7, dedicated-server, ffmpeg

I am looking to buy a dedicated server for my video project, I have multiple video upload at the same time each video I upload is about 2-3 GB in size and about 2-3 hours in length (TV Series/Movies). Currently I am using `Intel Xeon E5-1650V3` dedicated server with `128GB` of RAM with dedicated port link speed `1GBPS` but when I convert `mp4/avi` videos into `HLS` using `FFMPEG` it takes about 40 minutes to 1 hour on each video to convert but I need some faster solution that can do within less then 15 minutes.
Some hosting companies recommends to add GPU in it.

Please recommend me a dedicated server specification that can handle version conversion very fast. features I will be using
`CentOS7`, `FFMPEG`

Looking forward for recommendations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All NVIDIA GPUs starting with Kepler generation support fully-accelerated hardware video encoding and decoding. The hardware encoder and hardware decoder are referred to as NVENC and NVDEC.

NVENC and NVDEC can be effectively used with FFmpeg to significantly speed up video decoding, encoding, and end-to-end transcoding.

To compile FFmpeg with nvenc, the CUDA toolkit must be installed. It's not used by the binary later, but you need the CUDA libs.

It can be used by:

```
ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuda ...
```

There are more details about how to do that in [the NVidia docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/ffmpeg-with-nvidia-gpu/).

Comment: thank you so much that works for me